# capturing init script output in a variable

Tags: bash, stdout, init.d

I'm trying to capture the output of an init script into a variable but in this case it's not very straightforward because the init script is using log_daemon_msg and log_failure_msg.  Why does the output pass through this pipe successfully:

```
service tomcat7 start | grep Tomcat
```

but not this one?

```
service tomcat7 start | read OUTPUT; echo $OUTPUT
```

In the second example, the value of $OUTPUT is a list of all the init scripts, which is not what I expected.  Similarly, the following example also results in a list of everything in /etc/init.d:

```
OUTPUT=$(service tomcat7 start)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `read` sets the value of `OUTPUT` in a subshell. When the pipeline ends, the subshell exits, and the value of `OUTPUT` is lost. Use the third example.

Answer (score 0):

```
service tomcat7 start | 
while read OUTPUT
do
   echo $OUTPUT
done
```

This works because there are more lines than just one --  of output from the command.  You need multiple reads.  Because there are multiple lines sent out from the command.

Comment: This is identical to `service tomcat7 start`, and does not address the question of how to store the output in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It might already work and only seem to do not, if $OUTPUT contains special characters (for filename expansion) which are expanded. Try `echo "$OUTPUT"`.